# problems with data preparation

Tags: r, data.table

Sorry for the unspecific title. Here's the data.table of interest:

```
dt <- data.table(K=c("A","A","A","B","B","B"),Y=c("2010","2010","2011","2011","2011","2010"),Q1=c(2,3,4,1,3,4),Q2=c(3,3,3,1,1,1))
dt
   K    Y Q1 Q2
1: A 2010  2  3
2: A 2010  3  3
3: A 2011  4  3
4: B 2011  1  1
5: B 2011  3  1
6: B 2010  4  1
```

Let's say the values of K are persons, so we have two here. Quarters of year are stored in Q1 and Q2. Q2 is kind of a reference quarter-variable and the values always relate to year 2011). Now I want to pick those lines in dt, where, for each Person in K, Q1 lies in an interval of 4 quarters before the value of Q2.

**An example:**
Person A has value 3 in Q2, so values 2 (2011), 1(2011), 4(2010), and 3 (2010) should be picked. Considering this dataset, this would just be line 2. Value Q1=4 in line 3 is too large, value Q1=2 in line 1 is too small. For the second Person "B", only line 6 would be chosen. Not line 4, because this is the same quarter as in Q2 (I want only those smaller than the value in Q2, and line 5 is obviously greater than the value in Q2.

```
dt_new
   K    Y Q1 Q2
1: A 2010  3  3
2: B 2010  4  1
```

**To sum up**:
 A value of say 4 in Q2 would mean: Pick all values in Q1 smaller than 4 where Y=2011, and pick all values in Q1 equal or greater than 4 (so just 4), where Y=2010. result: 3(2011),2(2011),1(2011),4(2010). This rule applies for all values of Q2. All this should be done for each Person.

I hope my problem got clear. I think there are many ways to solve this, but since I'm still learning data.table, I wanted to ask you for nice and elegant solutions (hopefully there are any).

Thanks

**Edit:**
Nearly found a solution: This gives me a logical vector. How can I extract the lines in the dataset?

```
setkey(dt,K)
dt[,(Q1<Q2 & Y=="2011")|(Q1>=Q2 & Y=="2010"),by="K"]
   K    V1
1: A FALSE
2: A  TRUE
3: A FALSE
4: B FALSE
5: B FALSE
6: B  TRUE
```

without doing this:

```
log <-dt[,(Q1<Q2 & Y=="2011")|(Q1>=Q2 & Y=="2010"),by="K"]$V1
dt[log]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a vanilla row-wise filtering so you don't need to (or should not) use grouping (`by = "K"`), just do:

```
dt[(Q1 < Q2 & Y == "2011") | (Q1 >= Q2 & Y == "2010"), ]
```

or maybe something more flexible if you are going to use ranges other than just `4` quarters:

```
quarter.diff <- function(Q1, Y1, Q2, Y2) {
  4L * (as.integer(Y2) - as.integer(Y1)) +
       (as.integer(Q2) - as.integer(Q1))
}

dt[quarter.diff(Q1, Y, Q2, Y2 = "2011")  > 0L &
   quarter.diff(Q1, Y, Q2, Y2 = "2011") <= 4L, ]
```

This is not just more general, it reads much better and makes the *reference-year-is-2011* assumption explicit.

Notice how I was careful to convert all your columns into integers inside the `quarter.diff` function. Ideally, your year and quarter data would already be stored as integers rather than character or numeric.

Finally, if you are concerned that `quarter.diff` is called twice and speed is a concern, you can temporarily store the result as @Arun suggested in the comments:

```
dt[{qdiff <- quarter.diff(Q1, Y, Q2, Y2 = "2011")
    qdiff > 0L & qdiff <= 4L}, ]
```

Comment: You can reduce the double call to `quarter.diff` by assigning the result to a variable, say `w` and then doing: `which(w > 0L & w <= 4L)`, with which you could just do: `dt[quarter.diff(Q1, Y, Q2, Y2="2011")]`.

Comment: a minor syntax comment - you don't need a comma in `dt[i-expression]`